# What is a canonical way to find the actual maximum argument list length?

Tags: limit, arguments

Following [ARG_MAX, maximum length of arguments for a new process](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) it seems like `ARG_MAX` is wrongly (or at least ambiguously) defined on my Mac Mini 3,1 running Ubuntu 12.04:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX # arguments 
2097152
$ locate limits.h | xargs grep -ho 'ARG_MAX[ \t]\+[0-9]\+' | uniq | cut -d ' ' -f 8
131072
```

The actual limit seems to be somewhere between these:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp -d)"
$ touch $(seq 1 131072) && find . -mindepth 1 -printf x | wc -c && rm *
131072
$ touch $(seq 1 131073) && find . -mindepth 1 -printf x | wc -c && rm *
131073
$ touch $(seq 1 $(getconf ARG_MAX)) && find . -mindepth 1 -printf x | wc -c && rm *
bash: /usr/bin/touch: Argument list too long
```

I did a small search:

```
cd "$(mktemp -d)"
min=131072
max=2097152
while true
do
    search=$((min + (max - min) / 2))
    if touch $(seq 1 $search) 2>/dev/null
    then
        min=$search
    else
        max=$search
    fi
    [[ $((max - min)) -le 1 ]] && echo "ARG_MAX = $min" && break
done
```

Eventually this resulted in `ARG_MAX = 314290`, which doesn't seem to have any relation to either of the `ARG_MAX` values found before. Is this normal? Is there a simpler way to find the actual `ARG_MAX`?

Did I misunderstand the definition of ARG_MAX? It seems it's actually the [byte](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Argument-list-too-long) (or possibly character) length of the arguments with or without (?) the separating spaces. If it's really the byte length, are there also [other restrictions](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/#maximum_number)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's the length in bytes, including the environment.

Very roughly:

```
$ { seq 1 314290; env; } | wc -c
2091391
```

[linux sysconf](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)

> The maximum length of the arguments to the exec(3) family of functions.
>                 Must not be less than _POSIX_ARG_MAX (4096).

[POSIX 2004 limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html)

> Maximum length of argument to the exec functions including environment data.
>       Minimum Acceptable Value: {_POSIX_ARG_MAX}

Answer (score 3):

The page that you linked to about [`ARG_MAX`](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) states that as of kernel version 2.6.23 it is 1/4th the stack size. It even links to the [git commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=b6a2fea39318e43fee84fa7b0b90d68bed92d2ba) responsible.