# "Argument list too long": How do I deal with it, without changing my command?

Tags: command-line, kernel, xargs

When I run a command like `ls */*/*/*/*.jpg`, I get the error

```
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

I know why this happens: it is because there is a kernel limit on the amount of space for arguments to a command.  The standard advice is to change the command I use, to avoid requiring so much space for arguments (e.g., use `find` and `xargs`).

What if I don't want to change the command?
What if I want to keep using the same command?
How can I make things "just work", without getting this error?
What solutions are available?

Comment: Useful reading: [Bash FAQ 95](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095).  Without changing your command there's not much you can do besides recompiling to increase your argument list maximum size, or change your directory structure so that there are fewer files.

Comment: @jw013 based on the linux kernel version it may be possible to increase the argument list - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45161/8979 for details about the change in recent systems.

Comment: @UlrichDangel, Yup, it is possible!  See my answer; my answer shows how to do it (on Linux, with a recent enough kernel).

Answer (score 61):

On Linux, the maximum amount of space for command arguments is 1/4th of the amount of available stack space.  So, a solution is to increase the amount of space available for the stack.

Short version: run something like

```
ulimit -s 65536
```

Longer version: The default amount of space available for the stack is something like 8192 KB.  You can see the amount of space available, as follows:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

Choose a larger number, and set the amount of space available for the stack.  For instance, if you want to try allowing up to 65536 KB for the stack, run this:

```
$ ulimit -s 65536
```

You may need to play around with how large this needs to be, using trial-and-error.  In many cases, this is a quick-and-dirty solution that will eliminate the need to modify the command and work out the syntax of `find`, `xargs`, etc. (though I realize there are other benefits to doing so).

I believe that this is Linux-specific.  I suspect it probably won't help on any other Unix operating system (not tested).

Comment: You can verify like this that it worked:

$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
$ ulimit -s 65535
$ getconf ARG_MAX
16776960

Comment: Does this mean that if I make the stacksize unlimited with `ulimit -s unlimited` the command line size will be unlimited, too?

Comment: @UncleBilly I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.  getconf ARG_MAX does show an increase but the command line still fails.  In my case the argument list is 258k, which should fit comfortably in ulimit -s 60000 (which is in k).  There's some other limit kicking in that gives this message.

Comment: I suspect this solution is not working for some people because of how make ends up passing commands to the shell as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475221/why-do-i-get-bin-sh-argument-list-too-long-when-passing-quoted-arguments.  I could easily be wrong though

Comment: This answer does not seem to work as consistently as some of the others, but it is by far the simplest to use when it does work and I think may also be faster than options that use for loops or the "find" command

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `ls */*/*/*/*.jpg`, try:

```
echo */*/*/*/*.jpg | xargs ls
```

`xargs`(1) knows, what the maximum number of arguments is on the system, and will break up its standard input to call the specified command-line multiple times with no more arguments than that limit, whatever it is (you can also set it lower than the OS' maximum using the `-n` option).

For example, suppose, the limit is 3 arguments and you have five files. In that case `xargs` will execute `ls` twice:

1. `ls 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg`
2. `ls 4.jpg 5.jpg`

Often this is perfectly suitable, but not always -- for example, you can not rely on `ls`(1) *sorting* all of the entries for you properly, because each separate `ls`-invocation will sort only the subset of entries given to it by `xargs`.

Though you can bump the limit as suggested by others, there will still be a limit -- and some day your JPG-collection will outgrow it again. You should prepare your script(s) to deal with an infinite number...

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  This is not a bad workaround.  Two caveats: 1. This breaks on directories and filenames that have spaces in their name, so it's not a perfect substitute.  2. Is that going to run into the same issue with `Argument list too long`, but for `echo` instead of `ls`, on shells where `echo` is not a shell built-in command?  (Maybe that's not an issue in most shells, so maybe that's irrelevant.)

Comment: Yes, special characters in filenames are a problem. Your best bet is to use `find` with the `-print0` predicate -- and pipe its output into `xargs` with `-0` option.

`echo` is a shell built-in and does not suffer from the command-line limitation of `exec`(3).

Comment: This works with commands that expect the variable argument as the last parameter, such as for `ls`, but what do I do when I want to `mv` many files to a single dir, e.g. `mv * destdir`? If `*` gives the "too many args" error, I can't make `xargs` to pass the paths as the first at to `mv` somehow, or can I?

Comment: Check the man-page for `xargs` on your system -- on FreeBSD, for example, the `-J` will help you with this task. If on your OS there is no way to do this, you'll need to write a custom script to reorder the arguments. Something like: `destdir=$1; shift; mv "$@" "$destdir"`. Then give this new script to `xargs`: `.... | xargs newscript $destdir`

Answer (score 6):

This [Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060?page=0,0) gives 4 solutions. Only the fourth solution does not involve changing the command:

> Method #4 involves manually increasing the number of pages that are
>   allocated within the kernel for command-line arguments. If you look at
>   the include/linux/binfmts.h file, you will find the following near the
>   top:
>
> ```
> /*
>  * MAX_ARG_PAGES defines the number of pages allocated for   arguments
>  * and envelope for the new program. 32 should suffice, this gives
>  * a maximum env+arg of 128kB w/4KB pages!
>  */
> #define MAX_ARG_PAGES 32
> ```
>
> In order to increase the amount of memory dedicated to the
>   command-line arguments, you simply need to provide the MAX_ARG_PAGES
>   value with a higher number. Once this edit is saved, simply recompile,
>   install and reboot into the new kernel as you would do normally.
>
> On my own test system I managed to solve all my problems by raising
>   this value to 64. After extensive testing, I have not experienced a
>   single problem since the switch. This is entirely expected since even
>   with `MAX_ARG_PAGES` set to 64, the longest possible command line I
>   could produce would only occupy 256KB of system memory--not very much
>   by today's system hardware standards.
>
> The advantages of Method #4 are clear. You are now able to simply run
>   the command as you would normally, and it completes successfully. The
>   disadvantages are equally clear. If you raise the amount of memory
>   available to the command line beyond the amount of available system
>   memory, you can create a D.O.S. attack on your own system and cause it
>   to crash. On multiuser systems in particular, even a small increase
>   can have a significant impact because every user is then allocated the
>   additional memory. Therefore always test extensively in your own
>   environment, as this is the safest way to determine if Method #4 is a
>   viable option for you.

I agree that the limitation is seriously annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Bash system calls and its direct variants (arguments and environment variables), will yield "Argument list too long", if pool space limit was reached.

I found [how to avoid this limit](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/#avoid), while dealing with ***special characters*** in the file names (e.g. spaces), by using *printf* with *xargs*:

```
printf '%s\0' */*/*/*/*.jpg | xargs -0 ls
```

Comment: This seems to be changing the command, it also would also generate a different result since each batch of files would be sorted by `ls` individually.

Comment: @Kusalananda when I used `echo` instead of `printf`, file paths with spaces failed on "ls: cannot access ... No such file or directory". What is the error you're getting ?

Comment: Yes, why would you change `printf` to `echo`? What I said was that the _output_ of your command may be ordered differently from the command that the user in the question is trying to execute, would it have been possible to run it at all.

Comment: It's running what the OP wanted `ls */*/*/*/*.jpg`, but in a safer way, by breaking the multi-paths "/*/*/*/.jpg" arguments with xargs, and piping it to the "ls" command. (Regarding the echo, I thought you referred to other answer here).