# How to cause "Argument list too long" error?

Tags: shell, command-line, ulimit

Context for the question: According to [POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html), ARG_MAX is maximum *length* of command-line arguments to `exec()` family of functions. Which lead me to believe that's actual *number* of arguments, however that clearly didn't work:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
$ touch {1..18000}.jpg
$ rm *.jpg
$
```

Clearly, this works fine, despite being in length over 8192 items. According to [D.W.'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45584/85039), the `8192` is supposedly size in kB. So clearly the previous assumption was wrong.

This is where the actual question comes in: How do I figure out the amount of items that actually *will* get above 8192 kB limit ? In other words, what sort of computation I have to perform to ensure that `*.jpg` type of glob will result into `Argument list too long` error ?

Please note, this isn't a duplicate of [What defines the maximum size of single command argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument). I know about `getconf ARG_MAX` and `ulimit -s` values, that's not my question. I need to know how to *generate enough arguments in size that will be above the limit*. In other words, I need to find a way to get the error, not avoid it.

Comment: What is the result of `getconf ARG_MAX` for you?

Comment: @Jesse_b `2097152` . And I'm on Linux, btw

Comment: Are you trying to manually reproduce `xargs`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, I wanted to generate enough files to play around with various methods of handling `Argument list too long` error. So far I've figured out `ulimit -s` gives stack space, ARG_MAX is subset to that. I see so far that `getconf ARG_MAX` gives basically 2M by default for argument size, 8M for stack space.  So basically all I need to know is how to create enough filenames to go beyond 2M limit, so that when I do `*.jpg` in any command that involves `exec()` family of function would throw that error.

Comment: I think I figured out what needs to be done. I'll post answer once I confirm it works

Comment: Looks useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110301/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yep, and I commented on Stephane's answer. I think that's almost what I need, but he didn't include calculations on how he got specific number that ends the sequence

Comment: you can guess at what the limit is with a minimized environment, e.g. https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/asm/Darwin/x86_64/t/echo.t#L59

Comment: `ulimit -s` reports the stack size, which is unrelated to the size of the 'argument + environment' limit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Then how do you explain that when `ulimit -s` value changes, `getconf ARG_MAX` value also changes proportionally ?

Comment: I don't. I merely observe that on some systems (specifically macOS 10.13.5), using `ulimit -a` reports one line saying `stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192`, so on this system, `ulimit -s` directly affects the process stack size.  Referring to POSIX is no help; its `ulimit` command only affects file sizes.  I don't know why Linux changes `ARG_MAX` when the stack size changes.  On a Mac, both before and after `ulimit -s 2048`, `getconf ARG_MAX` still reports 262,144.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ POSIX [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) says: _{`ARG_MAX`} Maximum length of argument to the exec functions including environment data. Minimum Acceptable Value: {`_POSIX_ARG_MAX`}_  POSIX [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) says: _The number of bytes available for the new process' combined argument and environment lists is {`ARG_MAX`}. It is implementation-defined whether null terminators, pointers, and/or any alignment bytes are included in this total._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `getconf ARG_MAX` to generate a long list of `x` and calling an external utility with that as its argument would generate an "Argument list too long" error:

```
$ /bin/echo $( perl -e 'print "x" x $ARGV[0]' "$(getconf ARG_MAX)" )
/bin/sh: /bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

The environment and the length of the string `/bin/echo` will be included in what makes the error occur, so we can try to find the biggest possible number by subtracting these:

```
$ env
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

(I started this shell with `env -i sh`, so there's only the `PATH` variable in the environment)

```
$ /bin/echo $( perl -e 'print "x" x ($ARGV[0] - length($ENV{"PATH"}) - length("/bin/echo"))' "$(getconf ARG_MAX)" )
sh: /bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

Still too long.  By how much?

```
i=0
while ! /bin/echo $( perl -e 'print "x" x ($ARGV[0] - length($ENV{"PATH"}) - length("/bin/echo") - $ARGV[1])' "$(getconf ARG_MAX)" "$i" )
do
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

This loop exits for `i=8`.

So there's four bytes that I can't immediately account for (four of the eight must be for the *name* of the `PATH` environment variable).  These are the null terminators for the four strings `PATH`, the value of `PATH`, `/bin/echo` and the long string of `x` characters.

Note that *each* argument is null terminated, so the more arguments you have to the command, the shorter the combined length of them can be.

---

Also, just to show the effect of a big environment:

```
$ export BIG=$( perl -e 'print "x" x $ARGV[0]' "$( getconf ARG_MAX )" )

$ /bin/echo hello
sh: /bin/echo: Argument list too long

$ /bin/echo
sh: /bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

Comment: So `ARG_MAX` is actually a character count for the whole command line, or is it rather a buffer size? How does character encoding play into this?

Comment: @dessert `ARG_MAX` is the number of _bytes_ that the combined length of the environment and the command argument list, including the command name and any null terminators on each argument (and on environment variable names/values), can be. So multi-byte characters would take more space. It may be a kernel or library buffer size.

Comment: @dessert Unquoted whitespace between the command's arguments would not count, so it's not the length of the command line.

Comment: That’s true, but if command path and environment are included it’s not just the list of arguments to that command (but to the shell I assume?), that’s what I meant.

Comment: @dessert Correct (although I don't think the arguments _to the shell_ matter). See the end of my answer.

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed. Good answer as always.

Comment: If you play with that on Linux, remember that there's the 128 kB limit for the length of a single argument. That's usually much lower than the limit for the total length. Since that Perl generates a single string (without whitespace), it'll hit that limit.

Comment: @ilkkachu Oh? I did not know this. Is that really a limit on the size of a string, or is it _actually_ `PATH_MAX`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I've understood it's the limit on the argument string size, it's [discussed in the linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/170373). E.g. this would trigger it: `/bin/echo $( perl -e 'print "x" x $ARGV[0]' 131072 ) > /dev/null` (one less works). I think `PATH_MAX` is usually 4096 (again, on Linux), and I don't think it's related.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for pointing this out. That limit does not seem to be an issue on OpenBSD, but I'll find a Linux system somewhere and may update the answer when I have time.

Comment: Sorry, i hope i'm not too late. I actually have mixed results, and i'm confused. Running `which echo` returns `/bin/echo`. And so , i ran `echo \`perl -e 'print "x" x 1000000'\`` I got no error. But when i ran `/bin/echo \`perl -e 'print "x" x 1000000'\``, i got the `/bin/echo: Argument list too long.` error. Why is that so?

Comment: @lionel319 `which` explicitly looks for external commands. If `which` says that `echo` is found at `/bin/echo`, this may still mean that your shell has a built-in `echo` that will take precedence over the external one.  Test with `type echo`, or with `command -v echo` (does not show a path if it's a built-in).

Answer (score 8):

On many Linux distributions, you can find out what's the current value of ARG_MAX by running

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

A simple way to generate the message "Argument list too long" is to actually supply a long argument list; for example, on my system

```
/bin/echo "$(find / -xdev 2> /dev/null)"
```

works, but

```
/bin/echo "$(find / -xdev 2> /dev/null)" "$(find / -xdev 2> /dev/null)"
```

produces

```
bash: /bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

For an in-depth discussion, see "[Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands)" on Stack Overflow.

P.S. The length in question is the actual amount of memory needed to store the arguments and environment. It is not related to the *number* of arguments.

Comment: It's ever so slightly related to the number of arguments since each argument would need a null terminator. So having `helloworld` would use 11 bytes, while `hello` and `world` would use 12.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of listing all the files on the system, which takes forever and doesn't work on sparse systems, the command

```
/bin/echo {1..200000}
```

is a much faster (163ms) way to generate the error. For me `ARG_MAX` is `2097152` (2,097,152 on the order of 2 million) but the command still errors.

If your shell doesn't have `{start..end}`, you can use the somewhat slower (but still faster than listing files)

```
/bin/echo $(seq 1 200000)
```

If either command doesn't work, just increase the end value until it does, until `bash` runs out of memory, or until `seq` can't count any higher.

Comment: You don’t need `seq` for this, `/bin/echo {1..200000}` also works.

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister: Only if the shell supports this feature.

Comment: @DavidFoerster sure, but you mentioned Bash in your comment already.

Comment: @LucasWerkmeister good point, it's also exponentially faster

Answer (score 6):

To make it easier start a new shell (`exit` when done) and set the limit to a lower value (100kbytes):

```
$ bash
$ ulimit -s 100
```

With the example you used, the error could be triggered:

```
$ touch {1..100000}.jpg
bash: /usr/bin/touch: Argument list too long
```

But better to use something like `echo`. Understand that a builtin might not trigger an error, this command should work correctly:

```
$ echo {000001..100000}6789
```

Also note that the amount of bytes is well over the limit set above (1.1Mbyte):

```
$ echo {000001..100000}6789 | wc -c
1100000
```

But this command won't work:

```
$ /bin/echo {000001..100000}6789
bash: /bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

The limit is set by the size of the argument list in bytes added to the environment size of the shell.