# Precedence of subshells in relation to redirection?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, subshell

Shell: GNU BASH

I've been using the following command for a while now:

```
echo "$(fmt -w 50 < foo.txt)" > foo.txt
```

Without any issues. However, when I try:

```
fmt -w 50 < foo.txt > foo.txt
```

The file foo.txt gets turned into a blank file. I assume that this is because of something to do with precedence of redirection operators and subshells being parsed by the shell.

Searching the GNU BASH manual hasn't been very fruitful. 
Could someone please tell me if I missed something in the manual? I would really like to understand the reason for this behaviour so I can make further use of it and know about any cases where it might lead to trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Bash manual, [3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion):

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following
>   expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for later
>      processing.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)). If any words remain after
>      expansion, the first word is taken to be the name of the command and
>      the remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above (see [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)).
> 4. The text after the `=` in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>      expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

Command substitution is one of the expansions that take place in (2), and redirection takes place after that in (3). This doesn't have anything to do with subshells, it's purely due to the order in which the shell goes about doing things. `(fmt -w 50 < foo.txt) > foo.txt` would have resulted in a blank file too.

Comment: Do you mean `$(fmt -w 50 < foo.txt ) > foo.txt` in your example?

Comment: No, I meant `(fmt -w 50 < foo.txt) > foo.txt`, where `fmt -w 50 < foo.txt` is run in a subshell.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot that just plain parentheses execute the list inside in a subshell.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. The section could have been worded a bit clearer as it doesn't use the word "precedence" or that the list given is a "sequence".

Answer (score 2):

One could use the [`sponge` util](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
fmt -w 50 < foo.txt | sponge foo.txt
```

---

A note on the original:

```
echo "$(fmt -w 50 < foo.txt)" > foo.txt
```

1. First executed is `fmt`, its output gets put in a *string*, *i.e.* what's in the double quotes.  Nothing else happens until `fmt` finishes.
2. `echo` prints the string to *STDOUT*.
3. Meanwhile `echo`'s output is redirected with `>` to *foo.txt*.

Steps #2 and #3 occur more-or-less simultaneously.

The original code does have an issue.  Command lines have [length limits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451486/how-to-cause-argument-list-too-long-error).  If the input *foo.txt* is very large, specifically larger than the length of `getconf ARG_MAX`, the `echo` command will either fail or give incomplete results.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, It's a useful [partial answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers).  Meanwhile [*muru's* answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526649/165517) already explained it.  More generally, knowing *how* to do something often helps reinforce understanding the *why* of it.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the length limit to my attention. I will keep it in mind.