# Bash - How to reorganize files based on the dates in their names?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I am working with thousands of files whose names contain sequential dates ranging from 2001-01-01 to 2020-12-31.

A sample of such files can be seen below:

```
gpm_original_20010101.nc
gpm_cressman_20010101_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-1_radius-500km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010101_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-2_radius-250km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010101_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-3_radius-150km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010101_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-4_radius-75km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010101_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-5_radius-30km.nc
.
.
.
gpm_original_20010131.nc
gpm_cressman_20010131_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-1_radius-500km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010131_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-2_radius-250km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010131_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-3_radius-150km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010131_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-4_radius-75km.nc
gpm_cressman_20010131_cor_method-add_fac-0.5_pass-5_radius-30km.nc
```

and so on until `2020-12-31`. What I need to do is to reorganize these files into new folders based on years and months.

The directory tree needs to follow the logic `year` with sub-directories `months`, like this:

```
2001
    01
    02
    03
    04
    05
    06
    07
    08
    09
    10
    11
    12

2002
    01
    02
    03
    04
    05
    06
    07
    08
    09
    10
    11
    12
```

and so on. And the files should be moved to these directories based on the equivalent date in their filenames. For example: all files containing `200101xx` in their names should be moved to the `2001/01` folder.

What is the most straightforward way to achieve this using bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my proposal if I understood correctly:

```
for i in *.nc; do 
  [[ "$i" =~ _([0-9]{8})[_.] ]] && d="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  mkdir -p "${d:0:4}/${d:4:2}"
  mv "$i" "${d:0:4}/${d:4:2}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very simple and works as intended.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: why are you anchoring with the `[_.]`? I'm not saying it's wrong, just trying to understand. An elegant answer, BTW.

Comment: Thanks! OP' sample has two possibilities: `XXXXXXXX_` and `XXXXXXXX.`, so both have to be taken into account. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It just seemed that `_([0-9]{8})` would be sufficient. I was wondering why to also match the underscore or period.

Comment: @spuck You're right, but the idea is to be as thorough as I can with regex patterns. Imagine there'a file with `_123456789` in its name, it will match but it's not 8 digits, it has 9 digits. I know it seems not the case in OP's file names, but you never know. You could be go even further and verify that the pattern is indeed a date... but that would be more complicated stuff... and well, takes much more time :).

Answer (score 5):

Looping through years and months:

```
#!/bin/bash

for year in {2001..2020} ; do
  mkdir $year
  for month in {01..12} ; do
    mkdir $year/$month
    mv gpm_cressman_${year}${month}* $year/$month
  done
done
```

In case you have too many files with long names per year & month (you claim "thousands"), `bash` might reach its limits ("argument list too long"). Either [temporarily increase ulimit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45584/123460) or use `xargs`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for year in {2001..2020} ; do
  mkdir $year
  for month in {01..12} ; do
    mkdir $year/$month
    find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "gpm_cressman_${year}${month}*" |
      xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' $year/$month
  done
done
```

Comment: +1 for the hint on the `argument list too long` issue, which happens to me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the date is always in the same position in the filename, put this in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while $# -gt 0 ; do
    file="$1"
    shift
    year="$( echo "$file" | cut -c 14-17)"
    mnth="$( echo "$file" | cut -c 18-19)"
    [[ -d $year/$mnth ]] || mkdir -p $year/$mnth
    echo mv "$file" $year/$mnth
done
```

And call the script with:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*201*' -printf | \
    xargs -r the_script
```

Read `man bash find xargs mkdir mv`.

Remove the `echo` when you want to do it for real.

Comment: Could be slow regarding one run of the `while`-loop per file.

Comment: I like the use of `echo` as a [mulligan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mulligan). +1

Comment: date could be extracted with string manipulation *${file:14:8}* but i recommend *grep -oE '([0-9]{8})' | head -n1* to be more flexible