# The sed command shows that the parameter is too long

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I want to replace all `str1` strings in files in the current directory with `str2`. I use

```
sed -i s/str1/str2/g `grep str1 -rl   ./`
```

command or

```
sed -i s/str1/str2/g `grep str1 -rl --include="*.*"  ./`
```

There is an error that the parameter is too long. Can someone tell me why? I googled this command. I also read the introduction of `sed` and `grep`, and I feel that there are no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep str1 -rl .` generates the list of all files that contain `str1`. That list is simply too long. This is not a problem of `sed` or `grep`, but the amount of space your system provides to parameters. A [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command) of the "argument list too long" error can be found on this same forum.

One way of fixing that is with `xargs`:

```
grep -rl str1 . | xargs sed -i 's/str1/str2/'
```

`xargs` takes its input and calls `sed` repeatedly with appropriately sized portions of the entire input.

Since we don't know if there are weird filenames that contain special characters like spaces, ";", "|" and the like, a better way might be

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/str1/str2/' {} \;
```

`find` goes through all regular files and performs the substitution if the file contains *str1*. Calling `grep` to check if the file does contain *str1* is wasteful.

Note that these solutions, like your original question, assume that all files can be processed with `sed`, i.e. they are text files. If you are not sure about that, this code only runs `sed` after confirming that the file is a text file:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "file {} | grep -q text && sed -i 's/str1/str2/' {}" \;
```