# Why does `ls | xargs wc -l` format prettily?

Tags: bash, xargs

Running `wc -l` (line count) individually on a file gives:

```
λ wc -l pacman_Qemq.txt
235 pacman_Qemq.txt
```

But running `ls | xargs wc -l` gives:

```
λ ls | xargs wc -l
  242409 pacman_database.tar.bz2
     235 pacman_Qemq.txt
     235 pacman_Qem.txt
     807 pacman_Qeq.txt
     807 pacman_Qe.txt
     376 pacman_Qmq.txt
    2276 pacman_Qnq.txt
    2276 pacman_Qn.txt
    2652 pacman_Qq.txt
    2652 pacman_Qsq.txt
    2652 pacman_Q.txt
  257377 total
```

How can this be? Why did the `total` show up? Why are the entries aligned? Shouldn't `xargs` be running `wc -l` individually on each file?

Interestingly, `wc -l *` produces the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `xargs` will pass as many parameters on a single command line as it can - usually up to the shell limit of (IIRC) 256 characters. So the command you're using, `ls | xargs wc -l`, is functionally equal to `wc -l *`. The behavior I believe you're expecting is for `xargs` to run `wc` once for each file, which can be produced by adding the `-n` option, `ls | xargs -n 1 wc -l`.

Comment: +1 - although the argument length limit is likely significantly larger than 256 characters. See for example [What is a canonical way to find the actual maximum argument list length?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45143/what-is-a-canonical-way-to-find-the-actual-maximum-argument-list-length)

Comment: Note the "functionally equal" commands that you mention are only functionally equal if the number of files in the current directory is small. Also, using `xargs -n 1 wc -l` on the right hand side would not work as soon as a filename contains a space, tab or newline.